# Read multiple txt file into dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, txt

I have a txt file that is in the format

[image]

I want to load this into a data frame, with columns as headers and values as rows.

Comment: Please add data to your post as text rather than images. Also, throw some light on what you have done until now to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.read_csv` with `sep = " "`:

```
df = pd.read_csv({FILE_PATH}.txt, sep=' ', header=None)
df.set_index(0).T
```

In your case `sep` turned out to be `\t`. Besides that manually changing some rows is a better idea. I changed `Weather conditions` to `Weather_conditions`, and `Time_taken (min)` to `Time_taken_(min)`. I also skipped reading the last row that would cause too hassle:

```
df = pd.read_csv({FILE_PATH}.txt, sep='\t', header=None)
read_those = len(df) - 1

# We read again after learning how much rows the dataframe has, and skip
# reading the last row, note that I also add *nrows* parameter here:
df = pd.read_csv({FILE_PATH}.txt, sep='\t', header=None, nrows=read_those)
df = df[0].str.split(expand=True).set_index(0).T
```

Comment: I tried this but did not work, here's the link for the txt file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13BK_TXjN6dljYpMky5Bq_pIxPSI3dNk3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Check the edit, I skipped reading the last row for convenience sake

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('0.txt', sep='\t', header=None)

df = df[0].str.split(n=1, expand=True)

df = df.T

df.columns = df.iloc[0]

df = df[1:]

with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
    print(df)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.